Model's ForeignKey field rises not-null constraint event with `default=` set
My model :
def Maker(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

def get_default_maker():
    default_maker, created = Maker.objects.get_or_create(name="noname")
    return default_maker.pk


class Item(models.Model):
    maker = models.ForeignKey(
        Maker,
        verbose_name="Maker",
        on_delete=models.SET(get_default_maker),
        default=get_default_maker
        )

I have a Maker instance-plug "noname". I would like to assign it on Item creation if maker field not set (in form). But whenever I try to create an Item without setting maker field I get psycopg2.errors.NotNullViolation: null value in column "maker_id" of relation "stock_management_item" violates not-null constraint.
Ofcourse, I can manage that in view/form but I would like to understand why default value won't work.
UPDATE 1: View/Form added
View:
def add_stock_item(request):
    form = forms.ItemForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = forms.ItemForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect(reverse("items_list"))
    else:   
        return render(
            request,
            "stock_management/item_create_form.html",
            context={"form": form}
        )

class ItemUpdateView(UpdateView):

    model = models.Item
    form_class = forms.ItemForm
    template_name = "stock_management/item_update_form.html"

    def get_success_url(self) -> str:
        return reverse("items_list")

Form:
class ItemForm(forms.ModelForm):

    maker = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        label='Maker',
        queryset=models.Maker.objects.all(),
        widget=Select2Widget(attrs={"style": "width: 100%"}),
        required=False
        )
    
    class Meta:
        model = models.Item
        fields = ("id", "maker", "name", "item_type")

The form is shared between update/create views and both views having the same problem with empty/None maker field.

What is get_default_brand?

What if you use default_brand iso default_brand.pk?

@willeM_VanOnsem sorry for a typo. Still doesn't work (psycopg2.errors.NotNullViolation) no matter func returns default_brand or default_brand.pk. Debugging indicates that function set to default returns valid pk (int in my case). Even manual setting pk to default (default=3) still rises the same exception.

Can you share the logic of the view that renders the form?

@willeM_VanOnsem I've updated my question with data requested. Just now I tried to create Item instance in django shell without maker field set and default worked. But then it seems rediculous as it's useless when instance creates by form and only useful when created via Model.objects manager and without explicitly passing None value (just bypassing maker assigning).

Examine the generated INSERT statement. My expectation is that maker is included in the column list; thus, the default assignment will not be made at the database level. What is the value of maker in the form when no selection has been made?

@JohnH you are right. As per SQL queries : {'sql': 'INSERT INTO "stock_management_item" ("maker_id", "name", "item_type_id") VALUES (NULL, \'1234\', 30) RETURNING "stock_management_item"."id"', 'time': '0.001'}. Also form returns None for maker field.
